# How to find repeated values in multidimensional array in angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array, underscore.js

```
var arrayValues = [[2,3,5],[3,5]]
var commonArrayValues = _.intersection(arrayValues);
```

Currently it is working as,

```
_.intersection([[2,3,5],[3,5]])
    Result: [2,3,5]
```

But it should work as, (i.e outer array should be removed)

```
_.intersection([2,3,5],[3,5])
    Expected Result: [3,5]
```

Anyone kindly give me a proper solutions. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) with [intersection](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection) to get what you want:

```
var result = _.intersection.apply(null, arrayValues);
```

```js
var arrayValues = [[2,3,5],[3,5], [2,3,5,6]]

var result = _.intersection.apply(null, arrayValues);

document.getElementById('results').textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore.js"></script>

<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **intersection** *_.intersection(*arrays)*
>   Computes the list of values that are the intersection of all the arrays. Each value in the
>   result is present in each of the arrays.
>
> _.intersection([1, 2, 3], [101, 2, 1, 10], [2, 1]);
>   => [1, 2]

```
var arrayValues = [[2,3,5],[3,5]]
```

Here arrayValues is an array having 2 arrays. Where as _.intersection expects arrays as parameter and not an array having arrays.

```
_.intersection([2,3,5],[3,5])
```

Or

```
_.intersection(arrayValues[0],arrayValues[1])
```

will output as what you need.

Comment: Thats my problem. How to parse and remove that outer array?

Comment: I need to fetch the arrayValues[0], arrayValues[1] dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is using eval:

```
var arrayValues = [[2,3,5],[3,5]]
var evalString = '_.intersection(';

arrayValues.forEach(function (element, index){
  evalString += 'arrayValues['+index+'],';
});

evalString =evalString.slice(0, -1);
evalString += ');'
eval(evalString);
```

**evalString** would end being something like `_.intersection(arrayValues[0],arrayValues[1],...,arrayValues[n]);`